# ISA 2006 can run on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, isa-server

ISA 2006 can run on Windows Server 2008 32bits/64bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

ISA uses a kernal mode driver to perform its firewall duties which is not compatible with Server 2008 (which has a very different network stack).

Forefront Threat Management Gateway (TMG) 2010 has been released, and is the new version of ISA. It is supported on 2008 x64.

Comment: TMG2010 - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E05AECBC-D0EB-4E0F-A5DB-8F236995BCCD&displaylang=en

Comment: This is going to create an interesting situation for Microsoft's support lifecycle.  Windows 2003 End of Life is 14 July 2015; ISA 2006 End of Life is 10 January 2017, so you have a supported product, but no supported OS to run it on!

Answer (score -1):

ISA (Internet Security and Acceleration) Server provides the two basic services of an enterprise firewall and a Web proxy ISA runs in windows Server 2006 or higher.

Comment: Server 2006 and higher, huh?  What an awful bump to an almost 3 year old thread.